# Animating Progress Element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a `progress` element. That element looks like the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="progress-bar">
    <progress id="myProgressBar" class="progress" style="background-color:orange;" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button id="animateButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Animate</button>
</div>
```

When a user clicks the "animate" button, I want to fill the progress bar with an orange bar to 75%. The animation should take .5 seconds (half a second).

As shown in this [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/UwHz9b61dh), I'm stuck getting the animation to work. I tried using `setInterval`, however, the animation was really jerky. Plus, I couldn't get the bar to be orange. It was always green.

Is there a way to animate the value of a progress element for a smooth animation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In webkit browsers you can use a pseudo class to add a transition and color:

```js
$('#animateButton').on('click', function() {
  $('#myProgressBar').val(75);
});
```

```css
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    transition: width 0.5s;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="progress-bar">
    <progress id="myProgressBar" class="progress" style="background-color:orange;" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button id="animateButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Animate</button>
</div>
```

If you need wider browser support, you can iterate the value 'till you get to the target value to animate the bar. However, you can't change the color.

```js
function animateProgress($progressBar, val, currentVal) {
  currentVal = currentVal || 0;
  
  var step = val * 16 / 500;
  
  function animate(currentVal) {
    currentVal += step;
  
    $progressBar.val(currentVal);
    
    currentVal < val && requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      animate(currentVal);
    });
  }
  
  animate(currentVal);
}

$('#animateButton').on('click', function() {
  animateProgress($('#myProgressBar'), 75);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="progress-bar">
    <progress id="myProgressBar" class="progress" style="background-color:orange;" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button id="animateButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Animate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What about non-webkit browsers? And the transition from green to orange? Besides, OP doesn't seem to use jQuery.

Comment: I've added a more generic solution. Updating and animating the color can be done with the pseudo element, but It's limited to webkit and firefox (just color).

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm still concerned by the fact that OP doesn't seem to use jQuery.

Comment: OP uses JQuery in the link he added to Bootply.

Comment: My bad. They use it in the Bootply example, just the jQuery tag isn't set in the question, and it doesn't show up in it.

Comment: I like this solution. However, the bar is blue and the background is orange. I can't figure out how to make the bar orange and the background gray.

Comment: You can't style the progressbar with standard CSS. You can read more about this in the article [The HTML5 progress Element](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/).

Comment: @OriDrori - Thank you. I got it working with a small hack. Basically, I used your example and used the following style: `background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(orange, orange);`.

Comment: Nice to know about the background image.

Answer (score 1):

The same as the accepted answer, but simplified + with no jQuery:

```css
progress {
    background-color: orange;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    transition: width 0.5s;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
Click on the progress bar:<br>
<progress value="0" max="100" onclick="this.value=50;"></progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```js
document.getElementById("animateButton").onclick= function(){
 document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = "75%";
}
```

```css
#progressHolder{
background:grey;
height:20px;
width:300px;
}

#progress-bar{
background:grey;
height:20px;
width:0px;

transition:background-color 0.5s, width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="progressHolder">
  <div id="progress-bar">
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="animateButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Animate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery animation and set the time interval as  "slow", "fast", or in milliseconds.

```js
$("#progress-bar").click(function(){
    $("#myProgressBar").animate({width: "100px"},slow);
});
```

Comment: This is useless with the <progress> tag.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how it can be done using smooth CSS3 animation : no need for jQuery or even JS animation at all.

```js
var progressBar = document.getElementById("progress-bar")

document.getElementById("animateButton").onclick= function(){
 progressBar.style.width = "75%"
 progressBar.style["background-color"] = "orange"
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 30px;
}
.container #progress-bar {
  background-color: #008000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="progress-bar"></div>
</div>

  <br>
  <button id="animateButton" class="btn btn-secondary">Animate</button>
```

Comment: The questions says: "Animating Progress Element value". You just created another solution without the use of the <progress> tag.